# Profiling OpenCL application on Windows with NVIDIA GPU

Tags: profiling, opencl, nvidia, intel-vtune, nvvp

can you help me?
I'm developing OpenCL application on windows 7 x64. Hardware is Intel Core i5, NVIDIA GTX 770. OpenCL uses NVIDIA for acceleration.

If I'm trying to use Intel VTune Amplifier XE 2015 my application hangs on the end of profiling and doesnt return any report. Documentation recommends to disable all "Cn(ACPI Cn) report to OS" BIOS options. But it's absolutely unclear how to change my application code to avoid this hanging.

Also I've tried to utilize NVVP using this manual https://github.com/UoB-HPC/UoB-HPC.github.io/blob/master/_posts/2015-05-27-nvvp-import-opencl.md .
Unfortunately profiler generates an error:
Unable to profile application. "Another CUDA tool (profiler, debugger, memcheck) is currently running which prevents the application from being profiled". This error also appears when only NVVP is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I suggest you to upgrade to the most recent VTune version, VTune Amplifier XE 2015 is too old.

With your version I can also recommend you to try these options:

1. use another analysis type - e.g. Advanced Hotspots
2. do not enable OpenCL tracing in the analysis type - it is considered to be
   used with Intel Integrated Graphics only.

Comment: Have updated 2 XE 2016. Now application crashes in advanced hotspots mode when starting profile. Still have warning about Cn(ACPI Cn). Collected data cannot be displayed. Basic hotspots works well.